# Time-triggered flow is not working like time-triggered workflow in Salesforce

Tags: salesforcedx, visual-workflow, workflow, scheduled-job

When Loan is in Credit Underwriting Stage for more than 20 days we have to change the stage to Complete and we have created a record-triggered flow and added the scheduled path for changing the stage to Complete. But this is not checking the criteria while updating the loan. Even if the loan is in some other stage and not in Credit Underwriting its changing the stage to Complete.

In workflow time-triggered actions used to check the criteria while executing the action which was queued.

Any resolution on this?

Comment: Please show the record-triggered flow's entry criteria. Use [edit]

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is working as intended. The entry criteria for the flow is not meant to be the scheduled path's entry criteria. Instead, you should include a decision node in the scheduled path to check if the business logic should still run when it's triggered.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. I have included the decision node in the scheduled path and it's not working.
[image]

Comment: Hi there, if you're providing an update or clarification to your question then please use [edit] your question or add a comment rather than an answer. As it stands this is likely to be removed as it does not in fact answer the question you've asked.